# Convert items in a list to String in single quotes and commas in between using Java

Tags: java

I have a Java code as follows

```java
String val = null;
List<String> holders = new ArrayList<>();
holders.add("A");
holders.add("B");
for (int i = 0; i < holders.size(); i++) {
   val = "'" + holders.get(i) + "'" + ",";
}
System.out.println(val);
```

I wanted my val to be printed as `'A','B'`, but the output I am getting is `'B',`.

What can be done here to get the correct output?

Comment: `val+="'"+holders.get(i)+"'"+",";`, see the `+` in front of the equals sign

Comment: Use `holders.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java 8+, you may use streams to accomplish your task. In particularly, you will need `collect` method to join the elements. I hope it will help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String val = null;
    List<String> holders = new ArrayList<>();
    holders.add("A");
    holders.add("B");
    val = holders.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
    System.out.println(val);
}
```